# Not able to boot Ubuntu on Dell i7

Tags: boot, uefi, lubuntu, dell

I brought Dell XPS 13, Core i7 Laptop preinstalled with Ubuntu several years ago. Since there were soon some issues with the original Ubuntu OS, I had to reinstall the Ubuntu OS couple of times, which went pretty smooth. So basically I had/have experience booting an USB Drive and installing the Ubuntu/Linux OS.

The issue that I am writing this post is that I'm not able to install Ubuntu OS anymore and keep receiving error that
`No bootable device is found` , thought the same USB Device manage to be seen by my friend's DELL Laptop.

I followed this recipe from DELL thoroughly [1], where they mention the BIOS settings needed to install Ubuntu, however no result.
The settings I choose based on this page is following:

```
Boot Sequence : UEFI
Advanced Boot Options : Enable UEFI Network Stack
System Configuration -> SATA Operations : AHCI
Secure Boot -> Secure Boot Enable : Disabled
```

One stupidity that I did with not-so-stable old Ubuntu OS was to delete the partition completely. Since its been a while that I did it, can not recall clearly, but in principle there is no OS on this DELL laptop and not able to install one.

Any insight to fix this issue is highly appreciated.

[1] https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/e...cy-mode?lwp=rt

Comment: I would go back in to boot options and make sure boot from USB is still enable.  It should be, but maybe it got changed.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. 1) After power on; Press F12 key before the Dell logo comes up. 2) USB Stick failure, try another healthy bootable one with a healthy USB C to A hub to a different USB thunderbolt port. 3) Open the laptop and pull the NVMe SSD, plug-in to another computer and install Ubuntu, then bring back into XPS.